# Pass values from html to Action Class Struts

Tags: java, html, struts2

I am completely new to Struts and now I am facing some issues.

Here is my html code :-

```
<div id = "processingMode">
   <div id = "appButton">
      <input type="hidden" value="Cancel" name="flagValue" />
      <a href="**action Class path**">Cancel</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I want to retrieve hidden field values in the action class (or please let me know how to pass values from html to action class).

Can anyone help me to achieve this.

Comment: Krupa remember to always, always, always **indent the code**.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; why not just a form? Otherwise you can build the href using the flagvalue on JSP render, or via JS.

Answer (score 3):

In order to pass the hidden parameter value using struts
you first need to add the struts library and import the struts tag library
 Try this below code

```
<s:url action="actionclass">
    <s:param name="id" value="parametervalue" />
</s:url>
```

Comment: can you write the action class code snippet . So its makes helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**Hi Krupa**

To send hidden parameters from view page to action class, you have to use **`<s:hidden></s:hidden>`** struts tag. You can pass the parameters through the URL too. But that is not a best practice to do so when it comes to security.

so try to use struts tag to achieve desired task. find the following sample app code to get a better understanding :-

**View Page**

```
<s:form action="testAction">
   <s:hidden name="EmpName" value="DummyName" />
   <s:submit value="Submit" />
</s:form>
```

**Action class**

```
public class Employee extends ActionSupport {
   private String EmpName;

   // getters and setters

   public String execute() {
      System.out.println("Employee Name  :- "+this.getEmpName());
      return "success";
   }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="testAction" class="Employee">
   <result name="success"><path of your view page></result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
<a href="actionname.do?q=somevalue">Cancel</a>
```

In Action class, create a parameter `q` and its set and get methods